# Unserialize error when @runInSeparateProcess

Tags: php, phpunit

I am implementing a module that will provide an API to work with and manage PHP sessions. I am testing the `Session\Manager` implementation that will allow users to start sessions, set IDs, get IDs, destroy sessions, etc. I am testing the methods in this class in a separate process, by using PHPUnit's `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation. When I use this annotation I get an exception thrown by PHPUnit due to an unserialization error. When I do not use the annotation the test runs as expected and fails on null not being equal to false.

Here's the test causing the error. So far no implementation details have been made, all methods for the interface exist but perform no operations.

```php
class ManagerTest extends PHPUnitTestCase {

    /**
     * Ensures that if the session has not been started yet the sessionExists
     * method returns false.
     *
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     */
    public function testSessionExistsWhenSessionHasNotBeenStarted() {
        $Manager = new \Session\Manager();
        $this->assertFalse($Manager->sessionExists());
    }

}
```

I was able to trace the problem down to the following [`PHPUnit_Util_PHP::runJob()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7/PHPUnit/Util/PHP.php#L159) method. I am running PHPUnit 3.7.5 and the `runJob` method being invoked is:

```php
/**
 * Runs a single job (PHP code) using a separate PHP process.
 *
 * @param  string                       $job
 * @param  PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase   $test
 * @param  PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result
 * @return array|null
 * @throws PHPUnit_Framework_Exception
 */
public function runJob($job, PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test = NULL, PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = NULL)
{
    $process = proc_open(
      $this->getPhpBinary(),
      array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
        2 => array('pipe', 'w')
      ),
      $pipes
    );

    if (!is_resource($process)) {
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_Exception(
          'Unable to create process for process isolation.'
        );
    }

    if ($result !== NULL) {
        $result->startTest($test);
    }

    $this->process($pipes[0], $job);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    proc_close($process);
    $this->cleanup();

    if ($result !== NULL) {
        $this->processChildResult($test, $result, $stdout, $stderr);
    } else {
        return array('stdout' => $stdout, 'stderr' => $stderr);
    }
}
```

The line `$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);` results in `$stdout` being equal to a long string of `?`. In `$this->processChildResult` the value in `$stdout` is unserialized and the invalid value passed to this function triggers a warning, resulting in an exception being thrown. I've also been able to determine that the return value of `$this->getPhpBinary()` is `/usr/bin/php`.

Exception message thrown:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: ???...???"*???...??


Caused by
ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 10081 bytes
```

Thanks to hek2mgl the PHP code in `$job` can be reviewed [at this gist holding the output of a var_dump on $job](https://gist.github.com/4ec1857829af37ad73c3). I created a link as it is a fair amount of code and this question is already quite long.

I've reached the end of my knowledge for this particular domain and not sure how go about debugging this problem further. I'm not sure why the `@runInSeparateProcess` is failing and why the `$stdout` from running a separate process results in a long string of ? marks. What might be causing this issue and how could I go about resolving it? I'm at a standstill for this module as future tests will require running in a separate process to ensure sessions being started and destroyed don't impact tests.

- PHP: 5.3.15
- PHPUnit: 3.7.5
- Error caused in IDE and command line test runners

Comment: Hey! interesting question. I had some issues with `runJob()` a short time ago. Maybe you can clone my [hexdump](https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump) package from github to see what is really in that ???...??? string.

Comment: Also (maybe easier) you can just do `die($job);` or whatever to get the job.. the job is a php file that will being executed with `/usr/bin/php` as you mentioned. The script returns serialized php data as output. Would really like to see that output!!! :) please execute it manually after grabbing the code and add it to the question

Comment: @hek2mgl Very nice idea on getting the output of the `$job` variable. I'm reviewing it now to make sure there's nothing being exposed that might be confidential. I'll update the answer with a link to the output.

Comment: Without the other required files I cannot execute the test and can therefore say not much. What does the script output when you execute it like I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @hek2mgl I was able to trace down part of the problem to the $GLOBAL['__PHPUNIT_BOOTSTRAP'] require failing and causing a fatal error. But, even when I comment out or temporarily fix to a known path and attempt to unserialize the output I get false for the return value indicating an error. There's some other things going on that I need to try to track down. But all that will have to wait for tomorrow I'm afraid.

Comment: For me too ;) Will go to bed ... Will have a look at the question and see if you find something new..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what is going on here and boy is it a doozy.

During testing the framework attempts to preserve global state. In the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::run()` function the current globals are converted into a string of PHP code by `PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::getGlobalsAsString()`. I am currently using an autoloading library to take care of requiring appropriate class files. This class was declared in a variable that was in the global scope, causing a serialization of that object to be put into the `$GLOBALS` array created by `getGlobalsAsString()`. This serialization, for whatever reason, includes the null byte character `\u0000`. When you attempt to unserialize this you get an error and is ultimately causing the output to be corrupted as well.

I fixed this issue by create a function in my test bootstrap that creates the autoloading object outside of the global scope. Now that the script is no longer attempting to unserialize a null byte the script produces no errors and the test case works as expected. This is a really funky issue, not sure if its an error in my code, PHPUnit's code or an internal error with the `serialize` function.

---

Alternatively you can override the `run()` function in your test case and explicitly set the test case to not preserve global state. This is probably a cleaner solution as you could easily run into other issues with requiring all included files again as is the default behavior.

```
class ManagerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function run(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = null) {
        $this->setPreserveGlobalState(false);
        parent::run($result);
    }

}
```

Global state must be set *before* the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::run()` function is invoked. This is likely the only way to reliably set the global state preservation properly.

Comment: As of 2015, one can use the [`@preserveGlobalState disabled`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html) annotation.

Comment: This is really a helpful answer.saved my time.

Comment: I encountered this recently and in my case it turned out to be that the test with `@runInSeparateProcess` was explicitly calling `exit()`. It was an integration test executing a full PHP script with and capturing output buffering.

Answer (score 2):

The $job argument to `PHPUnit_Util_PHP::runJob()` is php code generated by PHPUnit that wraps the code of your test method in a way that it can be executed as a commandline script (clever trick!).
The isolated test will output serialized php data about test results back to phpunit.

You can investigate this code if you would add the following line on top pf `PHPUnit_Util_PHP::runJob()`

```
file_put_contents('isolated.php', $job);
```

After executing the failed test again the file `isolated.php` should have been created in the current directory. You can have a look at code can execute it (in the current folder) by typing

```
php isolated.php
```

Do you see any output that looks messy?

Also you should debug the method `PHPUnit_Util_PHP::processChildResult()`. The method is responsible for deserializing and checking test results. Place some echos or var_dumps there or use a debugger. When having a look at this method it is very likely that the problem is caused by illegal output from the test method.

Answer (score 1):

Please try set in php.ini:

> detect_unicode = Off

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is notheworthy that the same error will be thrown when your tested code calls `exit`.