# Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, lamp

I am trying to run the tests in PHPUnit and getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Class
>   __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer' in /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/PHP.php:237

```
PHP - 5.4.7
PHPUnit - 3.7.21
```

PHPUnit setting :

```
processIsolation = "true"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling this? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Class+__PHP_Incomplete_Class+has+no+unserializer Seems to be an issue specific to PHPUnit and symfony2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14514753/921154 might be related. When working with a framework that put a PDO connection in its global scope, the solution was to add that variable to the backupglobalblacklist: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/fixtures.html#idp7165424

Answer (score 11):

Try clearing the cache for the test environment. `php app/console cache:clear --env=test`

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work, I know the reason but i am not sure about it since i do not have any solution to it. This problem is due do the "GLOBALS" handling differently in PHP and PHPUNIT, i have even tried out this option(http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.backupGlobals)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a debugging solution that might help you finding where the unserialize method is failing:

```
<?php
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'debug_unserialize');

function debug_unserialize($classname) 
{
    die(var_dump($classname));
}
```

That way you will see which classname is causing problem.

Comment: Useful command. However, my output shows a class that does not exist. Any ideas on why that would be? I have a feeling it is due to something gone wrong with composer or the cache, but I have cleared both and re-installed composer packages

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your site in a browser and then again try to execute the test. I am sure it would work, it seems that there is some difference in cache generation by Php Unit and by Symfony

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue

updating symfony to symfony 3.3.18 works for me !

hope it helps