# phpunit You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

Tags: phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit with processIsolation="true" because I need to set cookie value in the code I'm testing, and without processIsolation="true" it can't be done. But in one of my test case, I'm getting the error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: [10-May-2018 15:23:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in -:394
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep()
#1 -(394): serialize(Array)
#2 -(536): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
#3 {main}
  thrown in - on line 394
```

Test case:

```
public function testUserCookieIsSavedToClicksTable()
{
    $cookie = sha1('12345');
    $_COOKIE['user_cookie'] = $cookie;
    $offerId = 1;
    $tx = $this->getTx($offerId);

    // Go
    $this->controller = new ClickController(new Click(new Database(Cache::getInstance()), new Queue, new RedisStorage()));
    $this->runLocal([1, $this->userId], null);

    $sql = 'select * from clicks order by id desc limit 1';
    $click = $this->db->query($sql, [], 'fetch');
    $this->assertEquals($tx, $click['tx_id']);
    $this->assertEquals($click['user_cookie'], $cookie);
}
```

This error is thrown  when calling any of `$this->assertEquals($tx, $click['tx_id']);` or `$this->assertEquals($click['user_cookie'], $cookie);`. But I can `var_dump` any variables used in those assertions.

I tried all solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492486/unserialize-error-when-runinseparateprocess) but they not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process Isolation require that all objects in the process to isolate can be serialized / unserialized.

The error you see is about a specific object that does not support PHP object serialization / unserialization.

That first of all means in the case you ask about, that you can not make use of process isolation for that test.

If you chew on that a bit and change some thoughts about what is going on here and why some objects (like database connections) normally can not be serialized and then as well, why process isolation might make use of serialization as well, it perhaps comes to mind as well why process isolation for database connections is not such a good idea after all.

So even though you see a technical limitation here that is causing the error, in the end I'd say it makes perfect sense to not run database connection based tests in isolated processes as part of the same testsuite.

This is perhaps not the answer you hoped for.

Perhaps divide and conquer can make sense here: Put those tests for which process isolation work into a testsuite of it's own and configure process isolation for it.

For the other one do the same into a testsuite of their own as well.

The PHPUnit XML configuration file offers settings to make these, sometimes it is even needed to have multiple of these XML configuration files, depends a bit on the Phpunit version used, but also for configuration settings for the test-runner.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there is also another issue, I need to run most or even all  tests in isolation because logic I'm testing is using cookies and phpunit is throwing the error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`, so I need to use isolation (unless you know the other way) but also I need to use DB connection :) So I don't think I can use separation of  tests here, I'll try to serialize Db component as @rob006 mentioned

Comment: Sounds like more an integration test-suite. If those tests need both (isoloation and the cookies) seems to be not so easy testable code then. It's common that tests reveal design flaws quite easily, and you might experience that (it's not inherently a bad thing, just saying). Sometimes w/ that it helps to disable cookies for sessions for example, you can control php ini values in the Phpunit XML configuration file as well. Also w/ that error message you should find some "inspiration" in other Q&A entries as well, but I can't suggest a specific one particularly well right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably error in your `db` component. It should implement [`__sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) method to make sure, that PDO instance is not serialized with it (and probably implement [`__wakeup()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup) to reconnect after deserialization).

You didn't share any informaction about `db` component, but this could be achieved by something like this:

```
public function __sleep() {
    $fields = (array) $this;
    unset($fields['pdo']);
    return array_keys($fields);
}
```

Comment: PDO does not implement these for a reason, it's worth to understand that reasoning before just implementing these (or to consider them at least when wondering about the follow-up problems this suggest may create). No rule w/o an exception, just saying.